# Programing pattern to load post compiled "objects" in c#

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

This doesnt really have a right or wrong answer and I am just looking for ideas, opinions or other experiance.

I want to do this in c#. Dotnet Core.

This isnt exactly what Im trying to do but it makes a better example and I can extrapolate from it.

Lets say I wanted to write a simple console app to decompress files.

you could do (ish) NOTE: This is far simpler than my real program.

```
main 
{
    switch(algo)
    {
       case "zip":
           zip();

       case "rar":
           rar();
    }

    byte[] zip() 
    {
        blah;
    }

etc. etc.

}
```

Now ignoring inheritance / interfaces etc. this is too hardcoded.

Lets say I wanted to do this but my main console program had no concept of what its decoding it just needs the same input / output methods etc.

its just:

```
Interface Decode {...........................................

main
{
    make a file whatever  < byte[] Decode something thats passed to me();
}
```

but the trick is the decode part is done by code written and compiled separately and post the main program.

folder structure:

```
\MyMain.exe (arguments passed as to what to decode)
\Decoders\rardecode.dll  Though note this is for .NET Core
          or rardecode.obj (maybe) 
          or rardecode.cs(compiled as needed) 

          zipdecode.dll  
          or zipdecode.obj .....
```

but the idea is anything can be added to the decode directory (in the same language c#), its compiled seperately (or not) (like plugins) following some kind of Interface.

Are there any patterns specific to this idea and is there a simple way to do this in c# are am I going to have to write some sort of object loader.

Its easy to do this with inheritance in the main code but its the plugin part thats important. After a little Googling I cannot put into words a simple way to search for ideas.

Hopefully all that makes sense.

Comment: You can look into MEF, it's very similar to a DI-container, but specifically built for this purpose. The idea is that you load components that are decorated with a special attribute. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Cool Ive never come across that before.

Comment: It seems to have a new name now for .Net Core "Microsoft Composition" https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Composition/